# In VS Code I just can't get command line arguments in launch.json working at all. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line, command-line-arguments

I just started using VSCode a few days ago and decided to try using it for Python. A quick google search tells me that the launch.json file is where you specify commain line arguments but for the life of it, I can't get that working. It looks as if launch.json is being ignore completely.

Here's a barebones program I made:

```
import sys
print("testing command line args")
print(sys.argv)
```

And here's what my launch.json file looks like. It's pretty much what the editor generated and I just added the args parameter:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": ["arg1", "arg2"]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's the output:

```
testing command line args
['d:\\Dev\\Python Projects\\test.py']
PS D:\Dev>
```

I've gone so far as to put gibberish in various launch.json parameters. It's all just being ignored. What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the command used in the terminal to run the script, are you using the launch config

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fter onfiguring launch.json file, you should click the run button in run and debug instead of directly clicking debug in the upper right corner of the file.[image]